# Problema para Consumir WCF através de uma API em C#?

Tags: c#, api, soap, wcf

Tenho uma API que preciso comunicar com um serviço de terceiros, para isso recebi a url do wcf. Sou novo ainda no assunto e por isso estou com problema em realizar a conexão com o serviço, porém é apresentado o erro dizendo que a operação não é suportada pela plataforma. O formato da conexão é o mesmo de uma antiga aplicação windows form que já utilizava o serviço.

O meu código até agora é o seguinte:

```
EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://***.**.***.**:****/SGAServico.svc?wsdl"), new DnsEndpointIdentity("***.***.*.***"));

WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;

binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;

SGAServicoClient conexao = new SGAServicoClient(binding, endPoint);

conexao.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "***";
conexao.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "*****";
conexao.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

Comment: já tentou usar o "Add -> Service Reference" para que o VS crie o código de conexão?

Comment: Já sim. Já está adicionado o wcf como serviço, mas para usa-lo preciso instanciar um objeto client, que é do tipo SGAServicoClient, e durante a construção do objeto tenho que passar dois parâmetros, o binding e o endpoint, que fornecerá um canal  de comunicação (e regras de comunicação) com o serviço, por fim para que eu possa usar o serviço preciso passar um usuário e senha que garantirá que um terceiro não faça uso indevido do serviço. Na hora de fornecer os parâmetros que algo está errado e por isso não funciona.

Comment: *" algo está errado e por isso não funciona."* isso é bem vago, precisamos de mais detalhes pra te ajudar, dá algum erro? já tentou fazer um *fiddler* pra ver como sai o requisição e a resposta do serviço?

Comment: Consegui encontrar o meu problema ele ainda não foi resolvido mas já existe um chamado para a Microsoft no seguinte link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476438/wcf-message-security-in-net-core

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO: Voltando para retornar como minha solução, com certeza não a ideal mas funciona. O ideal seria comunicar a incompatibilidade ao fornecedor do serviço e verificar um possível ajuste. Porém como o serviço já era antigo isto acarretaria em custos. Para resolver foi criado um outro serviço WCF que consumia o primeiro, porém utilizando BasicHttpBinding e tudo funcionou. Gostaria de uma solução melhor, mas por enquanto o problema foi solucionado. Agradeço a ajuda de todos!